hazelcast kubernetes discovery - nodes are not forming a cluster
We are using kubernetes discovery mechanism
When the second member is coming up and trying to form a cluster with the first member, it just prints a lot of "Connection closed by the other side" and then dies after some attempts. I think it discovers the first node's IP address and port, but for whatever reason the connection is not successful
When I enabled the trace logs, this is what I see
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableIOException: Packet not sent to -> [100.113.179.122]:5701 over null
at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil$1.create(ExceptionUtil.java:40)
at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.peel(ExceptionUtil.java:124)
at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.peel(ExceptionUtil.java:114)
at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.peel(ExceptionUtil.java:69)
at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:129)
at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil$1.handleException(FutureUtil.java:52)
at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.returnWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:274)
at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.returnWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:239)

Any pointers are greatly appreciated
Edit : Here is a longer Stacktrace

Scanning all invocations
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.264[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.h.i.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] NOT sending master question to blacklisted endpoints: {}
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.264[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.h.i.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Sending master question to [100.113.179.122]:5701
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.264[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cached.thread-2][0;39m [36mcom.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Starting to connect to [100.113.179.122]:5701
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.265[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cached.thread-2][0;39m [36mcom.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Connecting to /100.113.179.122:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.265[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[.BalancerThread][0;39m [36mc.h.i.n.nio.iobalancer.IOBalancer       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Adding pipelines: NioChannel{/0.0.0.0:39689->null}.inboundPipeline, NioChannel{/0.0.0.0:39689->null}.outboundPipeline
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.266[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cached.thread-2][0;39m [36mc.h.internal.networking.nio.NioChannel  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Successfully connected to: /100.113.179.122:5701 using socket Socket[addr=/100.113.179.122,port=5701,localport=39689]
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.266[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cached.thread-2][0;39m [36mc.h.nio.tcp.TcpIpEndpointManager        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Established socket connection between /0.0.0.0:39689 and /100.113.179.122:5701
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.266[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cached.thread-2][0;39m [36mcom.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Sending bind packet to [100.113.179.122]:5701
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.269[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[.IO.thread-in-0][0;39m [36mcom.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Connection[id=16, /0.0.0.0:39689->/100.113.179.122:5701, qualifier=null, endpoint=[100.113.179.122]:5701, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.270[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[-common.event-4][0;39m [36mc.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Removed connection to [100.113.179.122]:5701
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.270[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[.BalancerThread][0;39m [36mc.h.i.n.nio.iobalancer.IOBalancer       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Removing pipelines: NioChannel{/0.0.0.0:39689->/100.113.179.122:5701}.inboundPipeline, NioChannel{/0.0.0.0:39689->/100.113.179.122:5701}.outboundPipeline
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.746[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onMonitorThread][0;39m [36mc.h.s.i.o.impl.InvocationMonitor        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Scanning all invocations
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:14.748[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[onMonitorThread][0;39m [36mc.h.s.i.o.impl.InvocationMonitor        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Broadcasting operation control packets to: 1 members
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:15.264[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.h.i.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Claiming myself as master node! Asking to endpoints: [[100.113.179.122]:5701]
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:15.265[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cached.thread-3][0;39m [36mcom.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Starting to connect to [100.113.179.122]:5701
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:15.265[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cached.thread-3][0;39m [36mcom.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Connecting to /100.113.179.122:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:15.265[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[.BalancerThread][0;39m [36mc.h.i.n.nio.iobalancer.IOBalancer       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Adding pipelines: NioChannel{/0.0.0.0:55649->null}.inboundPipeline, NioChannel{/0.0.0.0:55649->null}.outboundPipeline
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:15.266[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cached.thread-3][0;39m [36mc.h.internal.networking.nio.NioChannel  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Successfully connected to: /100.113.179.122:5701 using socket Socket[addr=/100.113.179.122,port=5701,localport=55649]
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:15.266[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[cached.thread-3][0;39m [36mc.h.nio.tcp.TcpIpEndpointManager        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] Established socket connection between /0.0.0.0:55649 and /100.113.179.122:5701
[2m2024-04-09 22:34:15.266[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m1[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.h.i.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [100.113.178.16]:5701 [myawesomeapp] [3.12.8] com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableIOException: Packet not sent to -> [100.113.179.122]:5701 over null

com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableIOException: Packet not sent to -> [100.113.179.122]:5701 over null
    at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil$1.create(ExceptionUtil.java:40)
    at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.peel(ExceptionUtil.java:124)
    at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.peel(ExceptionUtil.java:114)
    at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.peel(ExceptionUtil.java:69)
    at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:129)
    at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil$1.handleException(FutureUtil.java:52)
    at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.returnWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:274)
    at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.returnWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:239)
    at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.claimMastership(TcpIpJoiner.java:216)
    at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.tryClaimMastership(TcpIpJoiner.java:171)
    at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.joinViaPossibleMembers(TcpIpJoiner.java:157)
    at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.doJoin(TcpIpJoiner.java:98)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:137)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:809)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:444)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:136)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:203)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:182)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:57)
    at com.koonthrix.ypfp.common.hazelcast.config.HazelcastServerConfiguration.hazelcastInstance(HazelcastServerConfiguration.java:119)
    at com.koonthrix.ypfp.common.hazelcast.config.HazelcastServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdacd881.CGLIB$hazelcastInstance$0(<generated>)
    at com.koonthrix.ypfp.common.hazelcast.config.HazelcastServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdacd881$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f709d4e2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.koonthrix.ypfp.common.hazelcast.config.HazelcastServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdacd881.hazelcastInstance(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableIOException: Packet not sent to -> [100.113.179.122]:5701 over null
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeRemote(Invocation.java:657)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:631)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:592)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:256)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:61)
    at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.claimMastership(TcpIpJoiner.java:211)
    at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.tryClaimMastership(TcpIpJoiner.java:171)
    at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.joinViaPossibleMembers(TcpIpJoiner.java:157)
    at com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner.doJoin(TcpIpJoiner.java:98)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:137)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:809)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:444)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:136)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:203)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:182)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:57)
    at com.koonthrix.ypfp.common.hazelcast.config.HazelcastServerConfiguration.hazelcastInstance(HazelcastServerConfiguration.java:119)
    at com.koonthrix.ypfp.common.hazelcast.config.HazelcastServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdacd881.CGLIB$hazelcastInstance$0(<generated>)
    at com.koonthrix.ypfp.common.hazelcast.config.HazelcastServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdacd881$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f709d4e2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.koonthrix.ypfp.common.hazelcast.config.HazelcastServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdacd881.hazelcastInstance(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(InvocationFuture.java:79)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:179)
    at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.executeWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:379)
    at com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.returnWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:269)
    ... 66 common frames omitted

